# How to make POST request using AJAX with Firebase?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my data saved in the URL `domain/data.json` as follows:

```
[{
"title": "first thought",
"content":
  {
    "desc":"This is the first thought",
    "img":"img.png"
  }
},
{
"title": "second thought",
"content":
  {
    "desc":"This is the second thought",
    "img":"img.png"
  }
}
}]
```

How can I make a POST request with AJAX to this data? I tried the code below, but it gave me bad request error. I also tried to test it from the chrome extension ARC, but it did not work as well.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://musing-83d85.firebaseio.com/thoughts.json",
  type: "POST",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    content:
    {
      desc:"This is the new thought",
      img:"imgn.png"
    },
    title:"new title"
  }, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form       fields and values)
  success: function(data){   // A function to be called if request succeeds
     this.setState({thought: data});
  }.bind(this)
});
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Please share the [minimal complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). An MCVE includes the JSON you post (present), the URL that you post to (missing), the code that you use to post (missing) *and* the error message that you get (missing).

Comment: You can't just `POST` data to a static file. You need a server-side process to handle the request. Why aren't you using the [Firebase database and JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your problem has a very simple fix. You may have figured this out on your own by now.

The json file you've posted above is NOT valid json. (see jsonlint.com)

Likewise, when using Firebase, try using only objects/objects of objects. 
( Here is a good article I found on why https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html )

Your ajax code looks fine, but you won't have a successful post unless you are sending valid json.  You can also try using a tool such as Postman to test your CRUD operations and your json data prior to typing the code.  I recommend that as well.

Hope this helps! Cheers!